# time complexity of this equation t(n)=t(n-1)*t(n-1)

Tags: time, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of this equation?
  the answer is 2^n but I   cant find solution.

```
 t(n)=t(n-1)*t(n-1)
```

Comment: It would be O(2**n) if poorly implemented.

Comment: Isn't that a logarithmic identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the base case is some finite constant, it should run in `O(2^n)` since for each call, it spawns two recursive calls.

For example, given a base case of `t(1) = constant`

```
t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant

t(2) = t(1) * t(1)
  t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
  t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant

t(3) = t(2) * t(2)
  t(2) = t(1) * t(1)
    t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
    t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
  t(2) = t(1) * t(1)
    t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
    t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
```

This could, however, be reduced to `O(n)` by caching the values (assuming no side effects)

```
t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant

t(2) = t(1) * t(1)
  t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
  t(1) evaluated in constant time cache lookup

t(3) = t(2) * t(2)
  t(2) = t(1) * t(1)
    t(1) = t(0) * t(0) = constant * constant
    t(1) evaluated in constant time cache lookup
  t(2) evaluated in constant time cache lookup
```

Comment: thanks.is there another solution by solving this equation:t(n)=t(n-1)^2

Comment: The equation itself isn't "solvable" really, it's more of a recurrence relation.  Determining the upper bound is mainly by identifying that for an arbitrary n, t(n-1) is called twice and in each call to t(n-1), t(n-2) is called twice [t(n-2) is called 4 times] and t(n-3) and so on

Comment: If you're looking for a proof, you can probably deduce it using proof by induction, but because its fairly simple you will need to reason that if each cast of t(n) results in 2 calls to t(n-1) then there will be O(2^n) calls to t

Comment: And in the case of t(n) = t(n-1)^2 then it is like the second situation since t(n-1) is calculated once per.  So it really becomes O(n) since you'll be calling it once per each n above the base case

Comment: t(n) calls t(n-1) calls t(n-2) etc. until t(1) or whatever your base case may be.  Squaring the result of a recursive call to t is done in constant time

Comment: can we say we have t(n)=2t(n-1)? and by master theory we have o(2^n)

Comment: If by that you mean you have 2 calls to t(n-1) then yes though I would not recommend that notation